# Default cell background in Calc

Tags: libreoffice-calc

Whenever I create a new document with Calc the cell background is set to white. Therefore the first thing I must do before start working is modifying the background to an eye-friendly colour (usually just grey).

Is there a way to set this default cell colour to avoid having to change it every time I create a new document?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another way would be to modify the overall color settings:

1. Menu "Tools" -> "Options"
2. in options: "LibreOffice" -> "Application Colors"
3. modify the very first color property "General" -> "Document background":

[image]

This will affect every document including writer and draw; it will affect every document independent from its source (assume working with a spreadsheet created by other people); and it won't affect other users working with your document (since it isn't a document / cell property but a user-specific application property). Of course, setting the cell background color manually or by using styles will override the general document background.

Answer (score 7):

One way is to change the default template:

- Create a new blank document
- Press <kbd>F11</kbd> to open the Styles editor
- Find the *Default* style and right-click then choose **Modify...**
- Set Background Color as desired
  [image]
- Click **OK**
- Click **File->Templates->Save as Template...**
- Choose a name, e.g. `Default`

  [image]
- Set the **Template Category** to **My Templates**
- Tick **Set as default template**
- Click Save

Now when you create a new Calc document it will use the template you just created.

Comment: Valuable answer, but [the one by tohuwawohu](https://superuser.com/a/1272779/288377) is leaner and solves the issue with all LibreOffice programmes.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa, your comment isn't what you asked in the question.  If you were interested in all of the LO apps, the question should have reflected that.  I had actually written an answer with the same solution as tohuwawohu's.  When James posted his answer, I realized that mine was written during a brain fart because his solution is the obvious, surgical way to accomplish what was asked without the "undesirable" effect on all other LO apps.  So I deleted mine.  If you desired the effect on all LO apps, that's a different question and answer.  But at least now readers will have both solutions.

Comment: @fixer1234 No, the other LibreOffice programmes are not a relevant to me, I do not use them. However, I think that other users that may in the future end up here will find tohuwawohu's answer more useful.