# LibreOffice Calc: modify default cell colour

Tags: libreoffice-calc

How can I change the default cell background colour in LibreOffice Calc? This to avoid changing it manually every time I create a new document.

Comment: Is https://superuser.com/questions/1272735/default-cell-background-in-calc no longer working?